# Select cells from different raster layers based on an index raster

Tags: r, terra

I have a raster that contains correction indexes and another raster with each layer representing the index and the layer value, the correction factor for a region. So wherever the index value is 1, I want the values from the first layer of the correction factor value. For index value 2, the second layer and so on.

I managed to solve this by using a mix of `sapp` + `cover` inside a `for loop`. I know, it's not pretty or fast.

Since I need to run this analysis for several index layers (thousands), I'd like something more elegant and fast. Any pointers?

Below is a reprex of what I'm doing right now:

```r
library(terra)

id <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
             ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
id <- rast(id)
id <- c(id, t(id))

factor <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
factor <- rast(factor)
factor <- c(factor*10, factor*100, factor * 1000)

compose_by_id <- function(id_lyr) {
  idf <- id_lyr
  # I know I have 3 possible id values
  # If index values are on the same range as correction factors, things break
  for (i in 1:3) {
    idf <- cover(idf, factor[[i]], values = i)
  }
  return(idf)
}

correction_factor <- sapp(id, compose_by_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectRange` for that, but that is not vectorized over the index layer, so you still need `sapp` or `lapply`.

```
library(terra)

id <- rast(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
id <- c(id, t(id))

factor <- rast(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
factor <- c(factor*10, factor*100, factor * 1000)

cf <- sapp(id, \(y) selectRange(factor, y))
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. I new there should be a better way. I was not aware of `selectRange`. Just out of curiosity, a benchmark showed that `selectRange` takes ~8 ms while my for loop solution takes ~24 ms.